# How to avoid magic string in class field_name in python, something like nameof() in c#

Tags: python, scrapy, magic-string

for example, in this python code.

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from myproject.items import Product

def parse(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
    l.add_xpath('name', '//div[@class="product_name"]')
    l.add_xpath('name', '//div[@class="product_title"]')
    l.add_xpath('price', '//p[@id="price"]')
    l.add_css('stock', 'p#stock]')
    l.add_value('last_updated', 'today') # you can also use literal values
    return l.load_item()
```

How to avoid use 'name', 'price' as a string. 
there are any way to use, something like

```
 l.add_xpath(getname(Product.name), '//div[@class="product_title"]')
 l.add_xpath((getname(Product.price), '//p[@id="price"]')
```

Thanks

Comment: Why? Scrapy Item instances will raise an exception if you make a typo. Is this just to get autocomplete support in an IDE, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

By using [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) builtin function

```
 product = Product()
 l.add_xpath(getattr(product, 'name'), '//div[@class="product_title"]')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but your solution, do not avoid to use magic string 'name'

Comment: name is not a magic string, however share your Product class in the first post and I'll update my aswer.

Comment: Thanks, again, maybe i don't be clear,   but my objetive is to get a compile error if field product.name is renamed. to do that, i need to avoid to use 'string' as field names. It's posible in c# with nameof() but no sure how to do that in python

Comment: You should use https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property and in the setter to add any kind of logic you want, including throwing an error if new name is different than old.